# How to unfold only protein atoms using Bio.PDB.Selection?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, pdb, protein-database

```
from Bio.PDB import PDBParser
from Bio.PDB import Selection
structure = PDBParser().get_structure('4GBX', '4GBX.pdb') # load your molecule
atom_list = Selection.unfold_entities(structure[0]['E'], 'A') # 'A' is for Atoms in the chain 'E'
```

When I unfold chain E in the PDB 4GBX using the code above, the last 2 Oxygen atoms in `atom_list` belong to water heteroatoms in the same chain. How can I get a list of only protein residue atoms and avoid other ligands or water molecules in the selection?

Comment: I seem to be a bit blind - 4gbx (https://www.rcsb.org/structure/4GBX) ... chain E? Are you speaking of atom number 6089 and 6091? However they belong to THR no?

Comment: 4gbx: chain E: water residue numbers 101 and 102: atom numbers 6190 and 6191. Thanks.

Comment: `atom_list[-1].get_full_id()
Out[21]: ('4GBX', 0, 'E', ('W', 102, ' '), ('O', ' '))` The 'W' here is for water heteroatom.

Comment: Yes, saw that too. However are you sure that the 'W' only occurs for heteroatoms? If yes, you can use something like `print([atom for atom in atom_list if atom.get_full_id()[3][0] == " "])` to filter your list ...

Comment: Thanks @quant . I think that should do the trick. I guess I need a coffee or two. I remember now that I had done the exact same thing some months ago.

Answer (score 0):

question code :

```
from Bio.PDB import PDBParser
from Bio.PDB import Selection
structure = PDBParser(QUIET = True).get_structure('4GBX', '4gbx.pdb') # load your molecule
atom_list = Selection.unfold_entities(structure[0]['E'], 'A') # 'A' is for Atoms in the chain 'E'

for i in atom_list :
    
    print(i , i.element, i.parent.id)
```

output:

```
...........
...........
...........
<Atom CA> C (' ', 93, ' ')
<Atom C> C (' ', 93, ' ')
<Atom O> O (' ', 93, ' ')
<Atom CB> C (' ', 93, ' ')
<Atom OG1> O (' ', 93, ' ')
<Atom CG2> C (' ', 93, ' ')
<Atom O> O ('W', 101, ' ')
<Atom O> O ('W', 102, ' ')
```

answer as per comments :

```
from Bio.PDB import PDBParser
from Bio.PDB import Selection
structure = PDBParser(QUIET = True).get_structure('4GBX', '4gbx.pdb') # load your molecule
atom_list = Selection.unfold_entities(structure[0]['E'], 'A') # 'A' is for Atoms in the chain 'E'

for i in [atom for atom in atom_list if atom.get_full_id()[3][0] == " "] :
    
    print(i , i.element, i.parent.id)
```

output :

```
...........
...........
...........
<Atom CA> C (' ', 93, ' ')
<Atom C> C (' ', 93, ' ')
<Atom O> O (' ', 93, ' ')
<Atom CB> C (' ', 93, ' ')
<Atom OG1> O (' ', 93, ' ')
<Atom CG2> C (' ', 93, ' ')
```